# Can't change notification url on team foundation server 2010 to domain name

Tags: tfs

Here is a bit of background on the setup:

1. I have a server called "File-Serv".
2. I have an NS entry that redirects clients.mydomain.com to the ip address of the modem which in turns forwards the request to the computer (this is all working perfectly so far)
3. I have apache running on port 80 and one IIS site running on port 8080
4. I installed TFS and changed the binding of the TFS site to use port 8081 so that it doesn't clash with the rest.

I installed team explorer on the server and was able to connect to TFS and add a project, etc.

The problem is now that i want to access TFS from all other computers on the network and more importantly still access TFS if i'm not connected to the local network but i can't

What i have tried is to change the notification url to clients.mydomain.com and change the binding on IIS to match. when i go to clients.mydomain.com:8081/tfs/web it asks me for a username and password

I do not have active directory installed and i have created users for all the users needed on the server but when whatever combination i put for username/password, i can never ever log in.

I've tried the following usernames with no success:

- Administrator
- File-Serv\Administrator
- clients.mydomain.com\Administrator

I'm really not sure what i'm missing here.. I have read forums upon forums without any resolution. Help!

P.S. This is my first question on stackoverflow after using the site religiously for 2 years now!

Comment: Since you are installed in workgroup, create the similar user account in your client machine with same password and try connecting to TFS.